# Retrieving Covid-19 pandemic statistics per country from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get the arrival date, the confirmed and recovery cases total and the deaths total of Covid-19 pandemic per country from DBpedia, using this query:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT distinct ?country ?arrivalDate ?confirmedCases ?recoveryCases ?deaths WHERE {
?country a dbp:location;
dbp:arrivalDate ?arrivalDate; 
dbp:confirmedCases ?confirmedCases;
dbp:recoveryCases ?recoveryCases;
dbp:deaths ?deaths
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ?country a dbp:location
> ```

With this triple pattern, you are trying to find entities that have `http://dbpedia.org/property/location` as type (`rdf:type`). This is not what you intend, because

- `dbp:location` is a property (not a class), and
- in the subject position, you don’t seem to want to find locations, but information about the pandemic.

So ideally rename `?country` to something like `?pandemicInfo` (for clarity), and then ask for the `dbp:location` of that `?pandemicInfo`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?pandemicInfo ?country ?arrivalDate ?confirmedCases ?recoveryCases ?deaths 
WHERE {
  ?pandemicInfo 
    dbp:location ?country ;
    dbp:arrivalDate ?arrivalDate ; 
    dbp:confirmedCases ?confirmedCases ;
    dbp:recoveryCases ?recoveryCases ;
    dbp:deaths ?deaths .
}
```

To only get information about the COVID-19 pandemic, you could add:

```
dbo:disease dbr:COVID-19
```

And if there is a type that all entities  share, e.g., `dbo:Pandemic`, you could add:

```
a dbo:Pandemic
```

(But you should verify if all the entities you are interested in contain these statements, otherwise you would exclude them.)